# Using sprintf in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I use sprintf in jQuery?

I'm trying to add an `id` to a chunk of HTML that is returned from a script

So:

```
success: function(html){
    $('.data').html($.sprintf(html,'TEST'));
},
```

The HTML that is returned is a large chunk of HTML where i've added a `%s` for sprintf to do it's replacement.

Eg: `'<div>Welcome to Blah</div><div>You userId is %s</div>'`

Comment: Here's a sprintf implementation to extend jquery: https://github.com/azatoth/jquery-sprintf

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If it's really as simple as you've described, just use `String#replace` with a regular expression (so you can use the `g` flag to make the replacement happen throughout the string):

```
$('.data').html(html.replace(/%s/g, 'TEST'));
```

Comment: Your solution worked really well. Just for my knowledge, cant sprintf be used in jQuery the way it's done in PHP. EG: sprintf($string,$m)

Comment: @Norman: Well, `$.sprintf` *does not exist*, so no, you can't use it. But of course you can create your own `sprintf` implementation and then you can use it.